# Strange border gradient for NSTextField(on ScreenShot)

Tags: macos, xib, nstextfield

I've got label attributes from designer: Connected - Helvetica Regular - 17 pt- #ffffff

I've set them in xib:

[image]

But here is what I've got

[image: Designer version is in the bottom]

In fact here is two "Helvetica Regular", but mine looks like bold.

Designer version doesn't have any colors instead of shades of gray, but mine has lots blue or red pixels. Also line width looks differ(designer's already noticed it). So... I have few questions about it:

- Do I have to worry about it?(probably it is just some kind of color smoothing)
- Are there some ways to make my screenshot the same as designer's?(or closer to source)

Extra info:

- macOS: 10.12.2 (16C68)
- Xcode: 8.2.1 (8C1002)
- Display: DELL U2312HM Display

P.S. Anyway. Thanks for attention.

Comment: Blue and red pixels? None such here on your screenshots. I would try another display... I just added a label, and I get the same result (as bottom of your last screenshot)

Comment: It's pretty strange. I'll try in a new project, and add some notes.